# TCP tracing in Golang

Tags: go, http, tcp, trace, handshake

Since golang 1.17 HTTP tracing was added providing valuable tracing hooks, alas, I am trying to get the connection information *attempt* (or, *before* it is established) and not the information on the established connection - what I am looking is the connection four tuple (source ip, source port, destination ip, destination port) which I can only get using -

```
trace := &httptrace.ClientTrace{
    // This is called once the TCP handshake has already been established
    GotConn: func(connInfo httptrace.GotConnInfo) {
        // Access the connection information
        conn := connInfo.Conn
        // Contains source ip & port
        localAddr := conn.LocalAddr()
        // contains the destination ip & port
        remoteAddr := conn.RemoteAddr()
     }
...
}
```

Is there any way to trace the attempt information? (i.e. right before the TCP SYN packet is sent for the TCP handshake?) I know I can use `GetConn` hook but it only provides the remote address and not the local one as well, unfortunately.

Comment: The local source IP and port of a TCP connection is usually determined by the OS when the connection is initiated, i.e. it is not known before your application asks the OS to establish the connection.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich gotcha! thanks a lot.. I guess there is no smart way to get those before the TCP handshake is established.